# Python Searching SQL Database and Decision Making

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, function

I am working on a program that connects to a SQL database and searches by email to find what admin account is associated with that users profile or if the user has an account. If the user does not have a account I want it to call the WebDat function and run. If the user does have an account I want it to call the password change function and pass all the credentials to the function. Currently it does all of this but it trys to run through twice. So If a user doesn't have an account it will create a user account twice. Is there a better way to make this program function?

Is there a better way to preform the decision making?

```
import email
from multiprocessing import connection
from sqlite3 import Cursor, Row
from tabnanny import check
from types import NoneType
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from psycopg2  import sql
import ADconnect
import PassChngWeb

def chckAcct():

    SQLEmail = ADconnect.email
    Hostname = 'ServerTime'
    IP_Address = '111.11.1.11'
    Driver_Name = 'SQL SERVER'
    Server_Name = "ServerTime"
    DATABASE_NAME = 'TimeToParty'

    connection_STRING = f"""
        DRIVER= {{{Driver_Name}}};
        SERVER={Server_Name};
        DATABASE={DATABASE_NAME};
        Trust_Connection=yes;
    """

    conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_STRING)
    print(conn)

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = "(SELECT Account_Number FROM DATacc WHERE Email_Address = '{email}')".format(email = SQLEmail)
    Check = cursor.execute(sql)

    # SELECT * FROM DATacc WHERE EXISTS

    # for x in cursor.fetchone():
    #     var = x
    #     print(var)

    check = cursor.fetchone()

    global AdminUser
    global AdminPassword
    
    if check is None:
        import WebDAT
        print("No user account found")
        AdminUser = '0'
        AdminPassword = '0'
        WebDAT.CreateAcct()

    for x in check:
        var = x
        print(var)

    if x == ('jsparky'):
        print("Username: JSparky")
        AdminUser = "jsparky"
        AdminPassword = "IMaLostBoy"
        PassChngWeb.ChangeLogin(AdminUser, AdminPassword)

    elif x == ("JSparky2/"):
        print(x)
        print("Username: JSparky2")
        AdminUser = "JSparky2"
        AdminPassword = "StillALostBoy"
        PassChngWeb.ChangeLogin(AdminUser, AdminPassword)

    elif x == ("jazzadmin"):
        print(x)
        print("Username: jazzadmin")
        AdminUser = "jazzadmin"
        AdminPassword = ("JazzHands")
        PassChngWeb.ChangeLogin(AdminUser, AdminPassword)

    elif x == ("adminMean"):
        print(x)
        print("Username: adminMean")
        AdminUser = "adminMean"
        AdminPassword = ("TooTheFloor")
        PassChngWeb.ChangeLogin(AdminUser, AdminPassword)

    elif x == ("RogerDat"):
        print(x)
        print("Username: RogerDat")
        AdminUser = "RogerDat"
        AdminPassword = ("ToTheWall")
        PassChngWeb.ChangeLogin(AdminUser, AdminPassword)

    elif x == ("LukeSkyWalker"):
        print(x)
        print("Username: LukeSkyWalker")
        AdminUser = "LukeSkyWalker"
        AdminPassword = ("TillTheSweat")
        PassChngWeb.ChangeLogin(AdminUser, AdminPassword)

    elif x == ("SuperKlein"):
        print(x)
        print("Username: SuperKlein")
        AdminUser = "SuperKlein"
        AdminPassword = ("DropsDownMy")
        PassChngWeb.ChangeLogin(AdminUser, AdminPassword)

    elif x == ("NoDetention/"):
        print(x)
        print("Username: NoDetention")
        AdminUser = "NoDetention"
        AdminPassword = ("Ballzzzz")
        PassChngWeb.ChangeLogin(AdminUser, AdminPassword)

    elif x == ("Vader"):
        print(x)
        print("Username: Vader")
        AdminUser = "Vader"
        AdminPassword = ("IamYouFather")
        PassChngWeb.ChangeLogin(AdminUser, AdminPassword)

    elif x == ("R2D2/"):
        print(x)
        print("Username: R2D2")
        AdminUser = "R2D2"
        AdminPassword = ("R2D2")
        PassChngWeb.ChangeLogin(AdminUser, AdminPassword)

    elif x == ("BabyYoda"):
        print(x)
        print("Username: BabyYoda")
        AdminUser = "BabyYoda"
        AdminPassword = ("FalconX")
        PassChngWeb.ChangeLogin(AdminUser, AdminPassword)

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but that **dangerous** SQL injection looks scary, you should fix it pronto

Comment: What dangerous SQL injection are you referring to? This script only queries the sql database

Comment: `sql = "(SELECT Account_Number FROM DATacc WHERE Email_Address = '{email}')".format(email = SQLEmail)` is SQL injection. Instead of using format strings or concatenation, use proper parameters. I believe in Python you would do something like `Check = cursor.execute("SELECT Account_Number FROM DATacc WHERE Email_Address = ?", (SQLEmail, ) )`